# How to implement swipe on particular part of view holder in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, android-viewholder

I have a view holder that has a **header** and **body** and I want to **implement swipe only on the body**, so the header stays in place. Any ideas how to do that?

I'm currently using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback for swipe to delete items in my recycler view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB0Ld.png)

```
    class ItemSwipeHelper() : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(1, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

    override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {

     // val itemView: View = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.item) // view holder body
        val itemView: View = viewHolder.itemView // view holder body and header
        val height = itemView.bottom.toFloat() - itemView.top.toFloat()
        val width = height / 3

        if (dX < 0) {
            val paint = Paint()

            paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(recyclerView.context, R.color.md_red_400)

            val background = RectF(itemView.right.toFloat() + dX, itemView.top.toFloat(),
                    itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())

            c.drawRect(background, paint)

            val icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(recyclerView.context.resources,
                    R.drawable.ic_delete_20)

            val dst = RectF(itemView.right.toFloat() - 2 * width,
                    itemView.top.toFloat() + width,
                    itemView.right.toFloat() - width,
                    itemView.bottom.toFloat() - width)

        }
    }

    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive) 
}
```

Comment: Not sure from a UIX perspective this makes sense that's why you aren't finding an out of the box solution. You would assume Google has put a lot of money into the UIX design and I don't think I've ever seen an app with a list of items that when swiped the header of the item stays and the body moves to the side. Just my 2 cents

Comment: @DavidKroukamp This is perfectly make sense though. The header usually is the static part of the list, so you don't want to swipe it.